# How to get a description of the meaning of the modifier keys (modN) of xmodmap?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I've read the documentation below on `xmodmap` (and `man xmodmap`):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap#Keymap_table

The documentation decribes modifier keys, and how to display the modifier map using `xmodmap -pm`:

```
$ xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x94)
mod3      
mod4        Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  ISO_Level3_Shift (0x6c),  Mode_switch (0x85),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

However, while `shift`, `lock` and `control` are self-explanatory, I cannot seem to find any reference or explanation of the meaning of the remaining `modN` modifiers.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

Cross-Answering from [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1057269/what-is-the-function-of-the-modifier-keys-in-xmodmap)

> X11 provides 8 modifiers to any keypress. You seem to have a fairly conventional set, where shift, control and lock have the obvious mappings.
> mod1 usually represents Meta or Alt, and mod2 to mod5 are available for whatever other modifier keys your keyboard has, often labelled Super or Hyper.
>  Usually these are not used for entering characters, but are interpreted by applications - for instance, in Emacs, I make Super+TAB equivalent to Meta+TAB:
> `(define-key function-key-map (read-kbd-macro "s-<tab>") (read-kbd-macro "ESC TAB"))`
> If you want your keyboard to generate characters using these modifiers, then xmodmap is not really capable enough, and you'll want to look into setxkbmap instead. That's a topic that's too big for this answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Modifier keys are keys that change the effect of a keystroke. In X, there are 8 possible modifiers, as listed by the output of `xmodmap -pm`. Not all of these are typically assigned to a key, that then is to act as a modifier key. As you see, `shift`is assigned to both the left and right Shift keys, `lock` to the Caps Lock key, `control` to the left and right Ctrl keys, etc.

> However, while shift, lock and control are self-explanatory, I cannot seem to find any reference or explanation of the meaning of the remaining modN modifiers.

These names are just names, i.e., `shift`, `lock`, `control`, `mod1`, `mod2` etc are just different labels for the available modifier states that can be defined in X. By traditional convention, the three first are assigned to the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> keys, and were given a meaningful name that refers to these keys. The other five modifiers acquired – and kept – generic names (`modx`).

So in the end, these are just "labels". If you wish, you could swap the key assignments around, and perhaps even start using `mod3`, although few applications would know what to with it - they do not foresee its use because it is not normally assigned to a key, hence used.